# Ранжированный поиск

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, pandas, поиск

Есть некоторая база данных содержащая некоторые названия и численность населения, пусть будут название городов, я создаю некоторую форму в которой человек предположительно хочет найти информацию о городе, но он не всегда знает корректное его написание, да и называть люди могут по разному (Питер/Санкт петербург, Санкт-Петербург) и я хочу выдавать человеку самый возможный вариант (т.е. в зависимости от похожести названия + учитывая популяцию, если город большой, то с большей вероятностью алгоритм поставит его на первое место в ранжировании результата.

Есть ли какие-то готовые алгоритмы или идеи насчет такого ранжирования в поиске по базе данных?

P.S. База данных - это обычная табличка в pandas.

Comment: не знаю, что такое pandas, то в SQL Server я помню был полнотекстовый поиск. Если же вы в памяти это делать собрались, то тут сильно зависит от ваших требований, в простейшем случае может и расстояние левенштейна подойти.

Comment: расстояние левенштейна сложно прогонять по всей бд, вы же понимаете.

Comment: вся бд лежит в оперативной памяти всегда, но из нее можно сделать какую-то другую структуру, лишь бы она решила поставленную задачу

Comment: Зависит от базы и количества записей в ней. Если всё в памяти и это просто список городов, то можно чем угодно пользоваться, это не займет много времени. Если же у вас даных много и нужен нечеткий поиск, то я бы смотрел в торону спец инструментов для этого, типа elasticsearch.

Comment: для списка городов можно название разбить на токены, выделить корень токена или посчитать буквы в нем и сделать то же самое с поисковым запросом -  но это конечно будет детским садом по сравнению с гтовыми решениями.

Answer (score 1):

Набросал по приколу вам готовое решение. Формулами и деталями реализации можно поиграться при желании:

```
# pip install fuzzywuzzy[speedup]

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

# берём сайт с готовой статистикой по крупным городам России, подготавливаем данные
url = 'https://sites.google.com/site/ruregdatav1/spisok-gorodov-rossii'
html = pd.read_html(url)
df = html[5].iloc[3:176,1:3]
df.columns = ['city', 'people']
df['people'] = list(map(int, map(''.join, map(str.split, df.people.values))))

# берём логарифм от размера населения городов
df['people_score'] = np.log1p(df.people.values)

# делаем поиск по конкретной подстроке
city_to_find = 'сара'
# вычисляем процент похожести каждого из городов на искомый
df['fuzzy_score'] = df.city.map(dict(process.extract(city_to_find, df.city.values, limit=df.shape[0])))
# домножаем на логарифм от населения, чтобы получить итоговый рейтинг
df['score'] = df.fuzzy_score * df.people_score
# выдаём 5 наиболее подходящих городов (с ненулевым рейтингом)
df.loc[df.score > 0].sort_values('score', ascending=False).head(5)
```

Вывод (форматировать мне лениво):

```
        city    people  people_scorefuzzy_score score
133 г. Саратов  838042  13.638825   90  1227.494222
132 г. Саранск  320612  12.677990   90  1141.019106
130 г. Самара   1156659 13.961047   68  949.351203
14  г. Барнаул  632391  13.357265   68  908.294002
10  г. Астрахань529793  13.180244   68  896.256560
```

Comment: Это неплохое решение, я что-то подобное писал, но у меня примерно миллион записей и каждый запрос обрабатывался больше секунды, что неприемлимо долго для меня(

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов У вас в списке миллион городов? А, ну если это не города и записей миллион, то, конечно, будет долго так. Тогда надо косинусное расстояние считать, это быстро, но вопрос в том, как для него готовить данные, это нетривиально будет.

Comment: Хотя если вам не надо по принципу "каждый с каждым" сопоставлять, то время будет терпимое и с левенштейном.

Comment: Ваше решение мне нравится, я вот думаю просто как-то может сделать разбивку данных хотя бы на 8 частей, чтобы время сократилось раз в 8, чтобы искалось как-то более менее логично, но пока не понимаю по какому критерию это сделать.

Comment: Я вам говорю, если хотите быстро - копайте в сторону косинусного расстояния. Вектор слов можно посчитать и записать заранее, вектор искомого слова вычисляется быстро, после этого ближайшие косинусы тоже моментально ищутся. Но не зная что за данные, непонятно как строить вектора. Для текстов это легко, например.

Comment: Если хотите распараллелить, можно произвольно разбить таблицу на части и считать score в отдельных потоках, потом по n лучших результатов объединить и ещё раз от них взять top n. В данной реализации спокойно можно считать score по любой части таблицы независимо от остальных частей.

Comment: Возможно, если ограничить у fuzzywuzzy число перестановок в параметрах, она будет быстрее считать, кстати, но надо пробовать.

Comment: Попробую через косинусное расстояние, действительно.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятна проблема.
Есть "некоторая" база данных - ну, наверное, в терминах Python -  датафрейм, в котором индекс - название города, а "некоторый" столбец содержит население.
Отсортировали свой датафрейм по этому столбцу. И работайте с ним как хотите.
Хотите - делайте подвыборку по начальным символам индекса и выдавайте ее в порядке вашей отсортированного датафрейма. А не хотите - сортируйте по индексу, а после ввода части названия -  делейте выборку из датафрейма и ее сортируйте.
Единственно, что непонятно, как вы Питер/Санкт-Петербург/Петроград/Ленинград отождествлять собрались - ну "похожесть названия" тут явно ни к чему. Но это совершенно отдельная задача.

Comment: Ну в том то и дело, что мне нужен какой-то алгоритм, понятно, что поиска синонимом не добиться без доп. базы, но хотя бы похожие названия явно можно было выделить, просто в данный момент у меня например клиент пишет петербург или питербург, а у меня только санкт-петербург записан в индексе, поэтому и встал вопрос.